# Encryption or security practice for single time use

Tags: encryption

Id like to encrypt a file and share it. I'd like the file to be decrypted just one time. I was wondering if there are security or encryption protocols that can be used to implement a 1 time use scenario. In simple terms the decryption key would only be good one time.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If I copy your key and ciphertext to two non-internet-connected computers, and decrypt it on each one, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: also, what would prevent sharing it once decrypted?

Comment: I believe you're looking for [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_%28paranormal%29). Or you could implement a server-based DRM system.

Comment: N.B.: would'nt a question like that be better on superuser?

Comment: You and every content provider on earth would like this.

Answer (score 3):

No it's **not possible**, with any kind of computer and any kind of OS.

What you want is called a DRM, and your file would need to be read by a program you've coded that would destroy the file (and the decoding key) after reading. But in order to protect the decyphering program from being copied, you'd have to sign the application against your OS, and make your OS protect that file from deletion. And in order to protect your OS from being copied with the file within, you'd have to use a computer that has a chip in the CPU making everything uncopiable... That's called trusted computing.

And though it may theoretically work, it would still be possible to keep a copy of your file, and use a super computer for up to 1000 years (or one hour, depending on your algorithm and the size of your key) to find your decription key, and thus access your precious content.

For the story, sony has tried putting DRMs in their CDs, and [that's what they end up creating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_BMG_copy_protection_rootkit_scandal).